# Logic built on "strings"

Tags: reference-request, logic

Are there (studied) logics or fragments of logic in which there are two unary functions Z, O that are used to build (binary) strings, for example:

- $\epsilon$ is the empty string,
- if $x$ is a string then $Z(x), O(x)$ are strings
- for all $x$, $Z(x) \neq O(x)$
- ...

and define some operations on them (e.g. equality, substring, ...).

In particular I'm interested in the boundary between decidable and undecidable logics that have those unary functions as their "core".

Comment: Is the idea that $Z(x)$ is the result of adding a zero to the end of string $x$, and $O(x)$ is the result of adding a one to the end of string $x$?

Comment: @MJD: yes (Z)ero, (O)ne

Answer (score 2):

There are some interesting papers :

- Andrzej Grzegorczyk, [Undecidability without Arithmetization](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/20016684?sid=21105747332901&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3738296) (Studia Logica, 2005)

and :

- Andrzej Grzegorczyk and Konrad Zdanowski, [Undecidability and Concatenation](http://www.impan.pl/~kz/files/AGKZ_Con.pdf) [into : Andrzej Ehrenfeucht & V.Wiktor Marek (editors), [Andrzej Mostowski and Foundational Studies](https://books.google.it/books?id=Ri4kjs-iGRgC&pg=PA72), 2008, page 72-on]

both based on Tarski's *concatenation theory*.